# How to make gdb print to other screen than the current one?

Tags: gdb

I am using gdb tui.
I learn from this site that we can use 'tty' to make the program output information through another terminal, and I also know that for the gdb print command, we can open gdb logging to redirect the output to logging files.

My question is:
 Is there a way to redirect the output of 'gdb print command' to another screen instead of to the log file?

I happen to have big structure , and with the gdb tui in place, Only half of the screen can be used to see the output of gdb print. Also, I can not scroll the window to see the full structure.

Answer (score 0):

> I happen to have big structure , and with the gdb tui in place, Only
>   half of the screen can be used to see the output of gdb print

You can temporarily leave tui mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> key binding, print big structure on full screen and go back to tui with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> key binding after you have done analyzing the structure. See [TUI Key Bindings](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html).